# Audio effects in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, effects

Does ffmpeg audio effects like reverb? Can I work with the channels (to detain them, mix)?  If so please link to code samples or examples of codes. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), which is like ffmpeg for audio.

Comment: These days ffmpeg can work with audio channels as well.

Comment: @rogerdpack it changes tempo, but ffmpeg still can't change pitch..

Comment: ffmpeg -i example.mp3 -af "asetrate=r=88K" -f mp3 -vn pitch_up.mp3

Answer (score 5):

You can use "RUBBERBAND" for changing pitch and tempo of audio,

If you want to change/add effect of audio from video file then use following code with combination of ffmpeg and  rubberband

```
ffmpeg -i w.mpg -vcodec copy -an tmpVideo.mpg
ffmpeg -i w.mpg tmpAudio.wav
rubberband -p 6 tmpAudio.wav tmpAudioRB.wav
ffmpeg -i tmpVideo.mpg -i tmpAudioRB.wav -vcodec copy finalVideow_6.mpg
```

This will generate a new video file with pitch change in audio

Comment: where can rubberband be found?

Comment: You can download it from http://rubberbandaudio.com/